# How to convert column A to text across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

If I manually change a cell from number to text it goes from 784768956303 to 7.84769E+11

Therefore I am currently using the code below to convert a number field to text on the worksheet that I am currently on.

```
Const MaxTextLength = 255

Sub ConvertColumnAtoText()
'    StartNewTask "Converting all cells to text"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")
    Dim cache() As Long
    cache = GetColumnWidths(MyRange)

    With MyRange
        .ColumnWidth = MaxTextLength
        Dim Values() As Variant
        ReDim Values(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)

        Dim col As Long
        Dim row As Long

        For row = 0 To UBound(Values, 1)
            For col = 0 To UBound(Values, 2)
                Dim temp As String
                temp = .Cells(row + 1, col + 1).Text
                If Len(temp) <= MaxTextLength Then
                    Values(row, col) = temp
                End If
            Next col
        Next row
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

    MyRange = Values
    SetColumnWidths MyRange, cache
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnWidths(Target As Range) As Long()
    Dim output() As Long
    ReDim output(1 To Target.Columns.Count)
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
        output(index) = Target.Columns(index).ColumnWidth
    Next index
    GetColumnWidths = output
End Function

Private Sub SetColumnWidths(Target As Range, widths() As Long)
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(widths) To UBound(widths)
        Target.Columns(index).ColumnWidth = widths(index)
    Next index
End Sub
```

This seems a bit overkill, but If I used

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
```

OR

```
[A:A].Select
With Selection
Dim col As Long
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I still got 7.84769E+11

What I would like to be able to do is run the script to convert the used range on column A on 3 different worksheets

I know I need to change this bit

```
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")
```

But I believe I can't have a range that covers multiple sheets.

Once all this is working, I would then like to add this to a button that is already calling 3 different macros and run everything sequentially once the previous macro is finished.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call courier1 'Macro1
    Call courier2 'Macro2
    Call courier3 'Macro3
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

However,  my original code above has 2 SUBs and a function (One SUB and the function as Private).   Would I need to change the button to

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call courier1 'Macro1
    Call courier2 'Macro2
    Call courier3 'Macro3
    Call ConvertColumnAtoText
    Application.Run "GetColumnWidths"
    Application.Run "SetColumnWidths"
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: When you `.NumberFormat = @`, the next step is that you have to loop through each cell to reset `.Value`.  eg:  `For each myCell in myRange: myCell.value = myCell.Value: Next myCell`

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb,  but how will that go across all the worksheets?   Or is this to remove the "function" and private "sub"?

Comment: That was just to simplify your method of changing the cell to text. To go through all the worksheets, something like: `Dim WS as Worksheet:For each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets: Set myRange = …  Next WS` and so forth.

Comment: Really sorry Ron,  I am still not understanding what you mean and which code I need to replace. (I am very new to VBA and given myself a pig of an overall starting project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your excel file has only the 3 sheets that you need to go through, below code will loop through all the sheets :

```
Sub ConvertColumnAtoText()
'    StartNewTask "Converting all cells to text"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim WS As Worksheet 'new line added

    Dim MyRange As Range

    For Each WS In Worksheets ' new line added

        WS.Activate ' new line added

        Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")
        Dim cache() As Long
        cache = GetColumnWidths(MyRange)


        With MyRange
            .ColumnWidth = MaxTextLength
            Dim Values() As Variant
            ReDim Values(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)

            Dim col As Long
            Dim row As Long

            For row = 0 To UBound(Values, 1)
                For col = 0 To UBound(Values, 2)
                    Dim temp As String
                    temp = .Cells(row + 1, col + 1).Text
                    If Len(temp) <= MaxTextLength Then
                        Values(row, col) = temp
                    End If
                Next col
            Next row
            .NumberFormat = "@"
        End With

        MyRange = Values
        SetColumnWidths MyRange, cache
    Next WS ' new line added

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Regarding your other

Comment: Thanks for this.   It helps a lot.